# How do I change the sound Lync makes when a new message comes in?

Tags: lync-2013

I'm using "Skype for Business (Lync)" at work for communications.

I went to its "Ringtones and Sounds" options page, which has a button labelled "Sound Settings". I go there, and set a new sound for "Incoming IM" under "Lync".

[image]

Despite having my new sound selected, and it playing properly when I click "Test", when new messages come in, it plays the default sound.

Comment: Did the changes get applied? Restart Skype and see if it changed.

Comment: I have done a full reboot of the computer. The new sound is still listed in the options dialog, but it still plays the default sound for a message.

Comment: I see another sound named `New Message`, try changing the sound for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the **Lync** category in the sound settings, there is another sound named *New Message*. Change the sound file used for that. I think this is the sound you are looking for.

[image]

I'm not sure what the *Incoming IM* sound is used for. Perhaps it is used for the first message from a contact or an IM from someone who isn't a contact.